# Color normalizations for different stretches

Tags: matplotlib

What's the best way to define a colorbar normalization in matplotlib?  For example, I want a `sqrt` normalization to concentrate values near 1.  The only normalization that changes stretch & is built in, as far as I know, is `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm`.

I've successfully written an `AsinhNorm` normalizer for [arcsinh normalization](http://code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/agpy/asinh_norm.py), but that is quite a bit of code for a relatively simple process.

Comment: That seems reasonable to me.

Comment: The answer may come from a pull request: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1780#issuecomment-14011100